# Firefox add-on tab-specific buttons and scripts, similar to Page Actions in Google Chrome

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, tabs, firefox-addon

I want to write a Firefox extension that acts exactly like the built-in RSS feed scanner (as an exercise). It should do the following:

1. On each new page / tab load, it should scan the content of the page for RSS feeds
2. If there are RSS feeds in the page, it should put a button in the location bar that the user can click
3. On clicking the button, a speech bubble should appear under the button (the way a speech bubble appears under the bookmarks star when you click on it), with information on the feeds and buttons to subscribe to them

So my main questions are:

- What is the process to run specific content scripts for specific pages?
- What is the process to use the results of those scripts to update the speech bubble for each location bar button for each tab?

**Basically, I'm trying to figure out how to do in Firefox what Page Actions are in Google Chrome.**

To clarify, I want to replicate this functionality in Firefox: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/pageAction.html

Please help! :)

Comment: Since there is already an RSS icon in the location bar for every page/tab, can I recommend you add your options to it instead? I like that Firefox has this indicator, but hate that it is tied to "live bookmarks". I just want the URL so I can copy it to Thunderbird, Google Reader, or whatever the RSS reader I use is.

Comment: scunliffe: I wanted to do this so that I can apply this method to create another extension that implements similar functionality (with something other than RSS feeds). That's why I want to know fully how this functionality works.

Answer (score 0):

This question is similar to this question:
[how to have tab-specific xul control with firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24257592/how-to-have-tab-specific-xul-control-with-firefox)

to have tab specific control. Usually (or maybe I am wrong),the newly added control is the same one across all the different tabs. Change from any tab will change its appearance in all tabs.

still looking for solutions or ideas.