# how to have tab-specific xul control with firefox

Tags: firefox, tabs, controls, xul

let me put it simple.
With Firefox 29,
I add a check box control next to the back & forward button in the toolbar "nav-bar".

It works. I mean I can do check and uncheck, and the javascript code will be triggered.

Now, my problem: after I checked the checkbox in one tab, I found that the checkbox in all other tabs are also checked, and if I uncheck any of them, the checkbox in all other tabs will be unchecked.

Why they change as one? I would like them to be unrelated or separated. In another word, I want the control (checkbox or button or label etc) to be tab-specific.

All suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Despite the fact that the URL bar and other navigation toolbar elements appear below the Tabs now in Firefox (wasn't always the case), the user interface still assumes there's only one of them. There's some customization done to the URL bar and server identity icon per-tab (URI), but that's basically it. If you want your element controlled/styled on a per-tab basis, you'll need to implement code to detect that. Have a look at how Firebug does it (can be individually activated per tab, and shows grey/coloured icon in navigation bar depending on per-tab activation).

Comment: Thank you for your information! Yes, I did it this: when a tab is chosen, I try to find out its current inner window ID, then find the data I associated to it, then I display something. @David-SkyMesh